# Can I implement a fair "wait on multiple events" with just events, mutexes, and semaphores?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

On a platform that only has events[1], mutexes, and semaphores[2] can I create a fair "wait on multiple events" implementation that returns when any of the events[3] is signaled/set.  I'm assuming the existing primitives are fair.

[1] Event is a "flag" that has 4 ops: Set(), Clear(), Wait(), and WaitAndClear().  If you Wait() on an unset event, you block until someone Set()'s it.  WaitAndClear() is what it sounds like, but atomic.  All waiters are awoken.

[2] I do not believe the system supports semaphores values going negative.

[3] I say "events", but it could be a new object type that uses any of those primitives.

Comment: The multiple wait should end when any of the events are signaled/set.  (Update: I just modified the question to indicate that after Jerry Coffin pointed out the ambiguity.  Thanks Jerry!)

Comment: Is an implementation that creates additional threads (or uses additional threads set aside in advance) acceptable?

Comment: I'd be curious to see it, but the platform has a very low limit to the number of threads, so it probably won't be helpful to me.

Comment: The idea I had in mind required at least 2+n threads, where n is the number of distinct events being waited on. One thread that, in principle, is waiting on any of the events, one thread that may signal one of those events, and n threads waiting in fact on each of the events. No good for you, I'm afraid.

Comment: "One thread that, in principle, is waiting on any of the events" -- That is the essence of the question, how would that thread wait on multiple signals such that it awakens when any of them are set?

Comment: what is the name of the platform?

Comment: @sp2danny: I think the goal was to have us treat it as an abstract platform.

Comment: `WaitAndClear() is what it sounds like, but atomic` this part is not clear. give link to manual, quite unusual feature.

Comment: @sp2danny: Huh? There's no need for a manual, it's pretty clear (no pun intended) -- it waits for the flag to become set, and as soon as that happens it clears the flag and returns to the caller. Just an atomic combination of Wait and Clear.

Comment: @PhilippeChaintreuil: You have to clarify what you mean by "fair", because to me fairness is a property of *multiple* calls to this function, not just a single call.

Comment: @Mehrdad In this case, I would consider "fair" to boil down to that no one has the chance to be starved.  A lot of implementations of similar problems have the issue that they count the number of threads waiting on the event and have the possibility for a new thread to come in during the waking up process and sneak through by stealing one of those counted slots.  Although, to be honest, I'm far less worried about such a chance than just finding a solution that is mostly fair.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, [WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) with the third parameter set to false should work (also includes a timeout option). I've also seen a similar wait function implemented for a in house developed small kernel used in an X86 (80186) embedded device. For an in house kernel, if the maximum number of threads is fixed, then each event, semaphore, ..., can have an array of task control block addresses for any threads pending on that object. Another option is to make a rule that only one thread can wait for any event, semaphore, ... , (only one entry for each object type that would contain either null or the address of a pending task control block) and in the case where multiple threads need to be triggered, multiple events or semaphores would be used.

Answer (score 1):

You need one of the following:

- A non-blocking event tester
- A ready made primitive, eg `WaitForMultipleObjects`
- One thread per waited object, plus some overhead

If you cant have one of those, i don't think its doable.

Comment: Is `WaitForMultipleObjects` even "fair" though? In what sense?

Comment: A "non-blocking event tester" sounds like it defeats the "wait" idea, as it sounds essentially that it's polling.  (Although it can be implemented with just the mutex and a sleep call by not using the events and just using atomic booleans.)  Let me know if I'm misinterpreting you.  "WaitForMultipleObjects" is cheating: I obviously don't have an equivalent or I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: I presume the multiple thread solution is allocate a new event, clear it, spawn a thread to wait on each of the multiple events and once they wake up, they set the new event.  (The "new event" must be reference counted to keep the threads from crashing after the first thread returns and wakes up the original waiting thread.)  I don't have enough threads available to implement this.  :-(